# keeping a toolstrip from scrolling when using a scrollbar in a panel using c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

i have a toolstrip that is docked to the top of panel1, I need to make sure that the toolstrip doesn't scroll when I use the panel1 scroll bar.
ive tried looking on the web and haven't found an answer, I figured I'd ask the pros for help. :) I would post an image, but I don't have enough rep apparently...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the toolstrip to be affected by it's parent control, then you should place it outside of that control.